# Поместить текст в scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

позволяет ли функционал сделать такое?
Есть вариант создать блок текста , и чтоб он перемещался в соответствии с положением скролла, но это криповый вариант.

Comment: Добавьте скрин желаемого, примеры вашего кода, что именно не получается?

Answer (score 1):

Можно соорудить что-то подобное на коленке.

```js
let width = 0;

const bar = document.getElementById('percent');
const val = document.getElementById('value');

let timer = setInterval(function() {
  width++;
  bar.style.width = width + 'px';
  val.innerHTML = (width / 3).toFixed(1);
  if (width > 300) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, 20);
```

```css
#scroll {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

#percent {
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: green;
}

#some-text {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll">
  <div id="percent"></div>
  <span id="some-text"><span id="value"></span>%</span>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если jquery-плагины для отслеживания скролла. Посмотрите, может подойдет плагин [ScrollSpy](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#scrollspy) из bootstrap